# Playwright - Target Closed before any action

Tags: automated-testing, page-objects, playwright, typescript

I am trying playwright and try to automate login feature. I have page classes, test classes and separate action class to write common actions like click,enter inputs.

My common action class

```
import { expect, Locator, Page } from "@playwright/test"

export default class Actions {

page:Page;

constructor(page:Page) {
    this.page = page ;
}

public async enterInput(value:string,element:Locator) {
    element.fill(value);
    await this.page.waitForTimeout(5000);
}

public async clickButton(element:Locator) {
    element.click();
    await this.page.waitForTimeout(5000)
}

}
```

My login.page.ts class

```
import { Locator, Page, expect } from "@playwright/test";
import Actions from "../common/actions";
import * as path from "../xpaths/xpath.json"
import fs from 'fs';


export default class LoginPage {

page: Page;
action:Actions;

inputUsername:Locator;
inputPassword:Locator;
btnLogin:Locator;
errorText:Locator;

constructor(page:Page) {
    this.page = page ;
    this.action=new Actions(page);

    const pathsxData = fs.readFileSync("json path here", "utf-8");
    const pathsx = JSON.parse(pathsxData);

    this.inputUsername = this.page.locator(path.usernameInput);
    this.inputPassword = this.page.locator(path.passwordInput);
    this.btnLogin = this.page.locator(path.loginBtn);
    this.errorText=this.page.locator(path.loginError)
    }

    public async login(username:string,password:string)
   {
    this.action.enterInput(username,this.inputUsername);
    this.action.enterInput(password,this.inputPassword);
    await this.action.clickButton(this.btnLogin);
    }

    public async successLogin(username:string,password:string,title:string){
    this.login(username,password);
    await expect(this.page).toHaveTitle(title);
    }

    public async invalidLogin(username:string,password:string,error:string){
    this.login(username,password);
    await expect(this.errorText).toHaveText(error);
    }

    public async emptyLogin(username:string,password:string,error:string){
    this.login(username,password);
    await expect(this.errorText).toHaveText(error);
    }

    }
```

My logintest.spec.ts

```
import { test , expect} from "@playwright/test"
import LoginPage from "../pages/login.page"
import * as data from "../testdata/testdata.json"

test.describe('Login Test', () =>{
let login:LoginPage;

 test.beforeEach(async({page}) =>{
    await page.goto("My Url");
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
    login = new LoginPage(page);
 });

test('invalid login-username/password both incorrect', async () => {
    login.invalidLogin(data.invalid_username,data.invalid_password,data.invalid_error);
});

test('empty username/password login', async()=>{
    login.invalidLogin(data.invalid_username,data.invalid_password,data.invalid_error);
});
test('successfully login to the system' , async () => {    
    login.successLogin(data.username,data.password,data.dashboard_title);
 });
 });
```

Whenever I execute the code always getting Target Closed error.Below is the error

```
Error: locator.fill: Target closed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('xpath=//input[contains(@id,\'outlined-basic\') and contains(@type,\'text\')]')
============================================================

   at ..\common\actions.ts:16

  14 |
  15 |     public async enterInput(value:string,element:Locator) {
> 16 |         element.fill(value);
     |                 ^
  17 |         await this.page.waitForTimeout(5000);
  18 |     }
```

But when I execute code without using action class like below code executes successfully.

```
import { test , expect} from "@playwright/test"
import LoginPage from "../pages/login.page"
import * as data from "../testdata/testdata.json"

test.describe('Login Test', () =>{
let login:LoginPage;

test.beforeEach(async({page}) =>{
    
    console.log(page.url)
   
    login = new LoginPage(page);
});

test('invalid login-username/password both incorrect', async ({page}) => {
    page.goto("http://192.168.0.127/ussd_qa/login");
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    await login.inputUsername.fill(data.username);
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    await login.inputPassword.fill(data.password);
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    await login.btnLogin.click();
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);
    await expect(login.errorText).toHaveText(data.invalid_error);
});
});
```

Can someone explain what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for another issue when I stumbled on your question. I think you're missing the `await`s in your `Actions` class for the `fill` and `click` methods (which you add correctly in your "without class" version).

Thus, the fill/click may not happen when you think, hence the error if it happens after the page has been closed.

Hope this helps ;-)